# Code Outputting Word Count Instead of Number of Vowels

Tags: python, python-3.x

When running this code, the output I get is the number of letters in the word rather than the number of vowels it has.

```
main():
    word = str(input('Give me a word '))
    vowels = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(word):
        if word[i] == "o" or "i" or "e" or "u" or "a":
            vowels += 1
            i += 1
    print('Number of vowels is: ' + str(vowels))

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with:

`if word[i] == "o" or "i" or "e" or "u" or "a":`

Basically, you are only checking if `word[i] == "o"`. You need to provide all the check like so:

You need to do multiple checks with the `word[i]` like so:

`if word[i] == "o" or word[i] == "i" or word[i] == "e" or word[i] == "u" or word[i] == "a":`

So your function should look something like this:

```
def main():
    word = str(input('Give me a word '))
    vowels = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(word):
        if word[i] == "o" or word[i] == "i" or word[i] == "e" or word[i] == "u" or word[i] == "a":
            vowels += 1
        i += 1
    print('Number of vowels is: ' + str(vowels))
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

#### Code:

```
def main():
    word = input('Give me a word ')
    vowel_count = sum(ch in set("aeiou") for ch in word)
    print('Number of vowels is: {}'.format(vowel_count))

main()
```

#### How does that work:

By using a set, it is faster to lookup if the letter in in the set.  Also iterating over the string allows one to test each character in the string to see if it is in the set of vowels.

Answer (score 1):

Why not `sum`:

```
word=input('Give me a word ')
print(sum(1 for i in word if i in 'aeiou'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def main():
...   word = str(input('Give me a word ')).lower()
...   return sum([word.count(x) for x in ['a','e','i','o','u']])
...
>>> main()
Give me a word This is a test string
5
>>>
```

Try this.
The problem with your code is that its incrementing 'i' only when it finds a vowel. Another problem is that

```
>>> bool('i')
True
>>> bool('o')
True
```

'i' and 'o' and the other characters are True by themselves, hence giving true for all the characters which makes it count all the characters and not just the vowels.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from `if word[i] == "o" or "i" or "e" or "u" or "a":`.

You only judge it if "o",and then `if word[i] == "o" or "i" or "e" or "u" or "a":` always ture. So each word was count as `vowels`.

**your origin code get into dead-loop,watch my mention below**

you should change to:

```
while i < len(word):
    if word[i] == "o" or word[i] == "i" or word[i] == "e" or word[i] == "u" or word[i] == "a"::
        vowels += 1
    i += 1 #btw you get dead-loop here on your origin code
```

But the best way is:

```
def main():
    word = str(input('Give me a word '))
    vowels = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(word):
        if word[i].lower() in ["o","i","e","u","a"]:
            vowels += 1
        i += 1
    print('Number of vowels is: ' + str(vowels))

main()
```